# Show datetimepicker last 6 days also know how to dynamically remove textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating one application where user can add dynamic textbox everything is working fine but in datetimepicker i want to show last 6 days in datetimepicker also i want to remove dynamic textboxes when user click remove button here is my code but it wont work **my main purpose is i want show last six days in datetimepicker and remove dynamic textbox one by one**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

         <style>

                .button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.button2 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #008000;
}

.button2:hover {
    background-color: #008000;
    color: white;
}

.button3 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #f44336;
}

.button3:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}

.button4 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.button4:hover {background-color: #e7e7e7;}

.button5 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #555555;
}

.button5:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: white;
}
.button6 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}

.button6:hover {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    color: white;
}
             </style>

        <script>

          //script for allow only 5 


        $(function () {
    $("#date_ex").datepicker({
        firstDay: 0,

        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            //var sunday = new Date("June 2, 2013 00:00:00");
            var sunday = new Date();
            sunday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            //alert(sunday.getDay() + ' : ' + sunday.getDate() + ' : ' + (sunday.getDay() || 0) + ' : ' + sunday.getTime());
            sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() - (sunday.getDay() || 0));
            var saturday = new Date(sunday.getTime());
            saturday.setDate(sunday.getDate() + 5);
            return [(date >= sunday && date <= saturday), ''];
        }

    });
    $("#date_ex").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy","setDate","-6d");
});






            var index = 0; 




            function getinput() 
            { 

            if($('[name*="txt_project_name"]').length == 5) return false;
            index ++; 
            var singleRecord = ""; 

            singleRecord += "Project_name : <input type='text'  name='txt_project_name"+index+"'>";
            singleRecord += "Project/Task : <input type='text' name='txt_Header"+index+"'>"; 
            singleRecord += "Department : <input type='text' name='txt_Department"+index+"'>"; 
            singleRecord += "Description : <input type='text' name='txt_description"+index+"'>"; 
            singleRecord += "Date : <input type='text' id='date_ex" + index+ "' name='txt_date"+index+"'><br/>"; 
            singleRecord += "<hr/>"; 
            $("#inputs").append(singleRecord); 
            var week = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6'];
            var date = new Date(), curDay = date.getDay();
            var minDate = curDay;
            var maxDate =week.length -  week.indexOf(String(curDay))-1;
            console.log(minDate,maxDate);
            $( "#date_ex" +index).datepicker({
            maxDate: "+"+maxDate+"d",
            minDate:  "-"+minDate+"d"
            }); 
            $("#count").val(index); 


            }
function removeElement()
{
    $('#inputs').find('input').remove();


}

            </script> 
            </head> 

            <body background="images\blue_background.jpg">
            <form action="EmployeeVendorValidation.jsp" method="post" autocomplete="off"> 


                 <br><br><br><br>    
            <input type="hidden" name="count" id="count"/> 
            <input type="hidden" name="date_ex" id="date_ex"/> 



            <div id="inputs"> 
            </div> 
            <button type="button" onclick="getinput()" class="button button5">Add</button> 
            <button type="button" onclick="removeElement()" class="button button5">Remove</button> 

            &nbsp; 
            <button type="submit" class="button button2">Submit</button> 



            </form> 

                <form action="ViewAndUpdateEmployeeTask.jsp" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" name="btnUpdate" class="button button2" value="UPDATE_SHEET"/>
                </form>
            </body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set minimum date and maximum date with `minDate` and `maxDate` parameter. For example to enable last 6 days

```
$("#date_ex").datepicker({
        firstDay: 0,
        minDate: -6,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            //var sunday = new Date("June 2, 2013 00:00:00");
            var sunday = new Date();
            sunday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            //alert(sunday.getDay() + ' : ' + sunday.getDate() + ' : ' + (sunday.getDay() || 0) + ' : ' + sunday.getTime());
            sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() - (sunday.getDay() || 0));
            var saturday = new Date(sunday.getTime());
            saturday.setDate(sunday.getDate() + 5);
            return [(date >= sunday && date <= saturday), ''];
        }

    });
```

And to remove the `textarea` you can use [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method. For example to remove all the `textarea` inside `inputs` id.

```
$('#inputs').find('input').remove();
```

Here is an working example.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#date_ex").datepicker({
        firstDay: 0,
        minDate: -6,
        maxDate: 0,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            //var sunday = new Date("June 2, 2013 00:00:00");
            var sunday = new Date();
            sunday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            //alert(sunday.getDay() + ' : ' + sunday.getDate() + ' : ' + (sunday.getDay() || 0) + ' : ' + sunday.getTime());
            sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() - (sunday.getDay() || 0));
            var saturday = new Date(sunday.getTime());
            saturday.setDate(sunday.getDate() + 5);
            return [(date >= sunday && date <= saturday), ''];
        }

    });
    $("#date_ex").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy","setDate","-6d");
});



            var index = 0; 




            function getinput() 
            { 

            if($('[name*="txt_project_name"]').length == 5) return false;
            index ++; 
            var singleRecord = "<div class='inputchild'>"; 

            singleRecord += "Project_name : <input type='text'  name='txt_project_name"+index+"'>";
            singleRecord += "Project/Task : <input type='text' name='txt_Header"+index+"'>"; 
            singleRecord += "Department : <input type='text' name='txt_Department"+index+"'>"; 
            singleRecord += "Description : <input type='text' name='txt_description"+index+"'>"; 
            singleRecord += "Date : <input type='text' id='date_ex" + index+ "' name='txt_date"+index+"'><br/>"; 
            singleRecord += "<hr/></div>"; 
            $("#inputs").append(singleRecord); 
            var week = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6'];
            var date = new Date(), curDay = date.getDay();
            var minDate = -6;
            var maxDate = 0;
            $( "#date_ex" +index).datepicker({
            maxDate: "+"+maxDate+"d",
            minDate:  "-"+minDate+"d"
            }); 
            $("#count").val(index); 


            }

$('.remove').on('click', function() {
if($('#inputs').children().length > 0){
    $('#inputs').children('.inputchild').last().remove();
  } else {
    alert('no input to delete');
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.button2 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #008000;
}

.button2:hover {
    background-color: #008000;
    color: white;
}

.button3 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #f44336;
}

.button3:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}

.button4 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.button4:hover {background-color: #e7e7e7;}

.button5 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #555555;
}

.button5:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: white;
}
.button6 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}

.button6:hover {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />


            <form action="EmployeeVendorValidation.jsp" method="post" autocomplete="off"> 


                 <br><br><br><br>    
            <input type="hidden" name="count" id="count"/> 
            <input type="hidden" name="date_ex" id="date_ex"/> 



            <div id="inputs"> 
            </div> 
            <button type="button" onclick="getinput()" class="button button5">Add</button> 
            <button type="button" class="button button5 remove">Remove</button> 
            &nbsp; 
            <button type="submit" class="button button2">Submit</button> 



            </form> 

                <form action="ViewAndUpdateEmployeeTask.jsp" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" name="btnUpdate" class="button button2" value="UPDATE_SHEET"/>
                </form>
```

Comment: No still is not working its giving last month two date and current months current week

Comment: @Atul do you want to display just last 6 days ? Then you add `maxDate: 0`,

Comment: @Atul you need to replace `textarea` with `input ` if you have input.

Comment: :$('#inputs').find('input').remove(); is working fine but if i want remove one by one then how can i do? also this maxDate: 0, not work

Comment: @Atul upload your html also. So that I can help you exactly the way you want.

Comment: i added my whole html

Comment: datetimepicker work as we expected but dynamic remove textbox still not working but thank you sir for your great effort

Comment: In which condition do you want to remove the text box?

Comment: @Atul on remove button click you need to remove by index.

Comment: when user click remove button only row of text should remove if he if there is no textbox pop up should come there is no textbox for remove like that

Comment: see here is image https://i.stack.imgur.com/X81mh.jpg when user click remove one row should be delete not all dynamic textboxes

Comment: @ 5740382: thank you sir :) you help me lot and page working as expected thank you very very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You May Simply Use it as follow

```
$("#excelFromDate").datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        maxDate: "0"
    }).datepicker("setDate", "-6d");
```

Comment: if i add maxDate: "0" then i unable to add dynmic textbox add button not work

Comment: If maxDate is not necessary you may ignore.